# ¿Como hacer que el desplegable no sea simplemente vertical?

Tags: css

Buenas, estoy haciendo un efecto para hacer una seríe de selecciones que van filtrando tu busqueda y eso lo he conseguido.

La cosa es que visualmente no queda como quiero. Ahora mismo me va apareciendo todas las opciones desplegandose de manera vertical.

¿Como podría hacer para que quedase como en el dibujo que he hecho?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir que sus "sub-opciones" se desplieguen al costado.

Código:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#Btn-Selector-Rutina').click(function() {
    $('.Btn-Selector-PushPull').fadeOut();
    $('.Btn-Selector-Weider').fadeOut();
    $('.Btn-Subselector-Rutina').fadeToggle();
  });

  $('#Btn-Subselector-Rutina-PushPull').click(function() {
    $('.Btn-Selector-Weider').fadeOut();
    $('.Btn-Selector-PushPull').fadeToggle();
  });

  $('#Btn-Subselector-Rutina-Weider').click(function() {
    $('.Btn-Selector-PushPull').fadeOut();
    $('.Btn-Selector-Weider').fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.Btn-Selector {
  height: auto;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  border: solid 2px;
  border-color: #21211d;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Btn-Subselector-Rutina {
  display: none;
  border-top-style: none;
}

.Btn-Selector-PushPull {
  display: none;
  border-top-style: none;
}

.Btn-Selector-Weider {
  display: none;
  border-top-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="Selector-Rutina">
  <p class="Btn-Selector" id="Btn-Selector-Rutina">Tipo de rutina</p>

  <p class="Btn-Selector Btn-Subselector-Rutina" id="Btn-Subselector-Rutina-Weider">Grupo muscular</p>
  <p class="Btn-Selector Btn-Subselector-Rutina" id="Btn-Subselector-Rutina-PushPull">Empuje - Tirón</p>


  <p class="Btn-Selector Btn-Selector-PushPull">Empuje</p>
  <p class="Btn-Selector Btn-Selector-PushPull">Tirón</p>

  <p class="Btn-Selector Btn-Selector-Weider">Abdomen</p>
  <p class="Btn-Selector Btn-Selector-Weider">Biceps</p>
  <p class="Btn-Selector Btn-Selector-Weider">Espalda</p>
  <p class="Btn-Selector Btn-Selector-Weider">Hombro</p>
  <p class="Btn-Selector Btn-Selector-Weider">Pectoral</p>
  <p class="Btn-Selector Btn-Selector-Weider">Piernas</p>
  <p class="Btn-Selector Btn-Selector-Weider">Triceps</p>
</div>
```

Gracias y un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear dos `divs` wrappers con `class = menu-wrapper`.

Estas dos divs wrappean un item del menú con sus subitems con `display:flex`, de modo que los subitems se van a acomodar en la misma linea que el item principal.

Quitando el `margin: auto` tienes espacio suficiente para que los subitems se acomoden a la derecha de cada item padre. **(Ver en pantalla completa)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#Btn-Selector-Rutina').click(function() {
    $('.Btn-Selector-PushPull').fadeOut();
    $('.Btn-Selector-Weider').fadeOut();
    $('.Btn-Subselector-Rutina').fadeToggle();
  });

  $('#Btn-Subselector-Rutina-PushPull').click(function() {
    $('.Btn-Selector-Weider').fadeOut();
    $('.Btn-Selector-PushPull').fadeToggle();
  });

  $('#Btn-Subselector-Rutina-Weider').click(function() {
    $('.Btn-Selector-PushPull').fadeOut();
    $('.Btn-Selector-Weider').fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.Btn-Selector {
  height: auto;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 2px;
  border-color: #21211d;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
   text-align: center;

}

.Btn-Subselector-Rutina {
  display: none;
  border-top-style: none;
}

.Btn-Selector-PushPull {
  display: none;
  border-top-style: none;

}

.Btn-Selector-Weider {
  display: none;
  border-top-style: none;
}

.menu-wrapper{
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="Selector-Rutina">
  <p class="Btn-Selector" id="Btn-Selector-Rutina">Tipo de rutina</p>

<div class="menu-wrapper">
  <p class="Btn-Selector Btn-Subselector-Rutina" id="Btn-Subselector-Rutina-Weider">Grupo muscular</p>
  <p class="Btn-Selector Btn-Selector-Weider">Abdomen</p>
  <p class="Btn-Selector Btn-Selector-Weider">Biceps</p>
  <p class="Btn-Selector Btn-Selector-Weider">Espalda</p>
  <p class="Btn-Selector Btn-Selector-Weider">Hombro</p>
  <p class="Btn-Selector Btn-Selector-Weider">Pectoral</p>
  <p class="Btn-Selector Btn-Selector-Weider">Piernas</p>
  <p class="Btn-Selector Btn-Selector-Weider">Triceps</p>
</div>

<div class="menu-wrapper">
  <p class="Btn-Selector Btn-Subselector-Rutina" id="Btn-Subselector-Rutina-PushPull">Empuje - Tirón</p>
  <p class="Btn-Selector Btn-Selector-PushPull">Empuje</p>
  <p class="Btn-Selector Btn-Selector-PushPull">Tirón</p>
</div>

</div>






</div>
```